# How to ensure column doesn't increase beyond a width percentage

Tags: css, flexbox

I've made a 2 column layout but the right column is stretching beyond 50% because of the `item-container` element.

https://jsfiddle.net/cd83mgex/

How can I make the column fixed to 50%?

**Column CSS:**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.column-1 {
  flex: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.column-2 {
  flex: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

Comment: show me your ideal result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `flex` property you're using is a shorthand for three properties: `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis`.

You're using it to set the basis to 50%. To ensure the split between columns remains equal, regardless of content, you need to set `flex-shrink` to 0. In order to do that with the shorthand however, you'll have to pass in a value for `flex-grow` as well.

Example:

```
flex: 0 0 50%;
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink

Comment: thanks, the scroll isn't showing for the item-container but it's another question :(